# show/hide divs and undo the hide per div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have another jQuery nested div question with showing and hiding nested divs.

This time, I can get the initial parent divs to hide, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it back up the chain again?

This is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="thing" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="undo">
    <a class="go-back" href="#">undo that?</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="thing" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="undo">
    <a class="go-back" href="#">undo that?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('.undo').hide();

 $('.thing').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest(".link").hide();
   $(this).parents().next(".undo").show();
   return false;
 });

 $('.go-back').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest(".undo").hide();
   $(this).parents().next(".link").show();
   return false;
 });
```

I always get confused on how to get it to target the correct inheritance, whether its parent, or child, or parents, or siblings, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is when you want to *undo* you search for the `next()` element but in the order of your markup now you want to search for the `prev()` element check this snippet:

```js
$('.undo').hide();

$('.thing').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest(".link").hide();
  $(this).parents().next(".undo").show();
  return false;
});

$('.go-back').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest(".undo").hide();
  $(this).parents().prev(".link").show();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="thing" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="undo">
    <a class="go-back" href="#">undo that?</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="thing" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="undo">
    <a class="go-back" href="#">undo that?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Bonus

You can resume this to just one click event like this:

```js
$('.undo').hide();

$('.item').on('click','a', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide().siblings().show();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="thing" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="undo">
    <a class="go-back" href="#">undo that?</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="thing" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="undo">
    <a class="go-back" href="#">undo that?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhhh, yep, that's it! Thanks! I would use the trimmed down example, but the way the HTML is structured it's nested within specific classes. I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help u mate @ultraloveninja

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, you need to go top two levels (parent().parent()), then find .link and show

```
 $('.undo').hide();

 $('.thing').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest(".link").hide();
   $(this).parent().next(".undo").show();
   return false;
 });

 $('.go-back').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest(".undo").hide();
   $(this).parent().parent().find(".link").show();
   return false;
 });
```